# ReactJS dynaminc component/routes based on user access

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I'm new into ReactJS - I'm trying to implement login system with PHP. 
I want to have different type of users - some of them should have access only to some portion of app.

Is there any way to prevent those users from accessing certain routes as /admin ?
What I want is not something as simple function that check's user accessible routes and redirecting -> I would like to HIDE/REMOVE components that user has no access to, so he would download the app containing only /login /info, so he won't even download /admin component in app (won't be able to see the code for it)

Comment: What's the issue if the user "sees" the source code for the admin ? If your app is well structured it's should not matter as the user could not use what he "downloaded".

Comment: I just want to restrict user not only from going to certain view/template/route but NOT TO HAVE IT at all. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Higher-Order Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html).

With HOC you can wrap other components.. if user have permissions you can return wrapped component, otherwise return null or redirect user to another route.

Comment: I think this is just simple redirecting - any user still can view the full code for admin routes he should not be able to preview in dev tools..

Comment: Just watched a video about ReactJS HoC - any user can go to network tab and download full source code of even protected pages. That's a big nono for me.